# Printing a 2d list with variable column lengths

Tags: python

so I have this 2d list:

```
grid = [
    ['hello', 'p1', 'p2', 'p4'], 
    ['later', 'p1', 'p4'], 
    ['no', 'p1', 'p3'], 
    ['dog', 'p3']
    ]
```

My goal is to print out this list in a format like this:

```
hello       p1 p2 p4
later       p1 p4
no          p1 p3
dog         p3
```

I've tried using this code to format the printing:

```
for i, val in enumerate(grid):
    print ('{:<30} {:>8}'.format(grid[0][0],grid[0][1],grid[0][2],grid[0][3],index[0][4]))
```

But I get a list index out of range error, I know that on some of these i'm trying to access an index that isn't there , because some have more columns than others but I can't figure out how to print this correctly.

Comment: try `...format(*(g for g in grid[i]))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> def format(grid, offset):
...     longest_word = max(len(row[0]) for row in grid)   # Get the longest word off all the rows
...     for row in grid:
...         str = '{} ' * len(row)
...         print(str.format(row[0].ljust(longest_word + offset), *row[1:]))
... 
>>> grid = [
...     ['hello', 'p1', 'p2', 'p4'], 
...     ['later', 'p1', 'p4'], 
...     ['no', 'p1', 'p3'], 
...     ['dog', 'p3']
... ]
>>> 
>>> format(grid, 3)
hello    p1 p2 p4 
later    p1 p4 
no       p1 p3 
dog      p3 
>>>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer, could you help explain this to me? I don't understand whats happening especially in line 4 str = {}?

Comment: @serenitynow13 In python, multiplying a string creates a string that is the original string repeated the amount of times its is multiplied by. By multiplying `{} ` by the length of the row, we dynamically get the same number of string interpolation slots for each entry in the array row. I.e. for the first row in `grid`, this would look like `{} {} {} {}`.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the rows of the arrays like this:

```
for row in grid:
    print(row[0],'     ',end='')#printing the first word and the spaces.
    for word in row[1:]:#starts the loop from the second word
        print(word+' ',end='')#printing other words in the same line.
    print('\n')
```

Edit:My answer doesn't print it symmetrically though, if that's what you wanted.

Comment: I don't think you can slice word like word[1:] in the second loop? You have to slice it after the loop statement?

Comment: @RichardKYu Right,edited the answer. I meant ````row[1:]````.

Answer (score 1):

Good question!

One way I can think of, would be to design some equation for the length of first entry and the number of tabs afterwards, that you would want to add:

```
grid = [
    ['hello', 'p1', 'p2', 'p4'], 
    ['later', 'p1', 'p4'], 
    ['no', 'p1', 'p3'], 
    ['dog', 'p3']
    ]

output = ''
for l in grid:
    length = len(l[0]) # This would be the length of first element in the nested list
    tab_counter = 1+ length % 4 # Here is the equation you might want to design and find out the number of tabs after ...
    output += f"{l[0]}" # printing the first element
    for k in range(tab_counter):
        output += "\t" 

    # Then you would simply print other elements
    for i,j in enumerate(l):
        if i is not 0:
            output += j + " "
    output += '\n'

print(output)
```

Still wouldn't print the desired output though:

```
hello       p1 p2 p4 
later       p1 p4 
no          p1 p3 
dog             p3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
max_title_length = max(map(lambda x: len(x[0]), grid))
for title, *parameters in grid:
    print(title, ' '*(max_title_length-len(title)), *parameters)
```

is less verbose.